# What happens to a wheel moving with constant velocity as it moves from a section of graveled road to ice

Tags: friction, free-body-diagram

Does the velocity of the wheel change (and it skids/slides) or does it remain constant? The coefficient of friction will be lower on the ice, but is there any other force that counters that to keep the constant velocity?

Comment: Certainly [rolling resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance) force depends on the ground nature as per [resistance coefficient](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240809/wheel-sinkage-depth) : $$ C_{rr} \propto \sqrt{\frac{1-\sigma^2}{E}} $$ where $\sigma$ is Poisson ratio of the ground and $E$ - Young's Moduli of the ground. So, depending on the combination of these factors on the new road type,- assuming wheel is moving just from inertia,- it will move longer/shorter/same timespan. But which scenario will be on asphalt -> ice transition, I'm too tired to analyze.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically the wheel can roll with constant angular and linear velocity without the need for static friction as long as there are no external forces acting on it necessitating friction for traction. Under those conditions it can theoretically transition from the gravel to ice without skidding.

If, however, the vehicle were accelerating or braking, or otherwise relying on the gravel for traction, it would lose traction upon encountering the ice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that in most cases, a car for example, is dependent on traction to generate just enough force to keep the car moving at constant velocity, so if the force required for this purpose was not greater than the frictional force of the ice, it might travel without non-slipping. This is of course covered in Bob D's post under the clause of "otherwise relying".

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus yes. An example of “otherwise “ for a car is traction is needed to maintain constant speed to overcome air drag

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the wheel was rolling purely before entering ice, it will continue to roll in the same manner without the need of any friction. Friction is required only when starting the rolling motion (that is when force is applied).Theoretically and in an ideal situation a rolling wheel will continue rolling despite the ground being rough as there is no relative motion between the point of contact and ground while rolling and so no friction acts. This is true only if we consider the wheel to be ideal, that is it is rigid and doesn't deform even a little .In such a case, the wheel will move with constant velocity and angular velocity. In a real situation, your wheel will act as follows:

1. It will enter the ice from the gravel and will continue rolling (as it was initially rolling).
2. Since the wheel is not ideal, the wheel is always deformed a little bit at the lower front end. This causes normal forces which generate torque opposite to the direction of angular velocity. Soon, the rolling object stops.

Comment: Seems you are ignoring rolling resistance, which DO depend on the ground Young modulus and Poisson ratio, because sinkage depth depends on them. Which may be different for ice vs asphalt. See my comment to the OP.